# Get only specific data from json which is defined as array

Tags: javascript, html, json

JS File:

```
"myJS": [
{
"language": "Arabic",
"symbol": "ar",
"text": "تعمل  على تحسين تصميم وأداء الهياكل والمواد والأنظمة للمشاريع من كل حجم ومستوى 
 التعقيد."
},
{
"language": "Dutch",
"symbol": "nl",
"text": "optimaliseert het ontwerp en de prestaties van constructies, materialen en 
systemen voor projecten van elke omvang en elk niveau van complexiteit."
}
]
```

Html File

```
<script>    
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJS);
if(myObj.language == "Dutch")
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.text;
}
</script>
```

Many Languages in JS File,
If language is Dutch then show only "text" in dutch language in html.
If I call only dutch language text then it shows only that. Nothing to change in JS File
OR
Get specific data from this link, If name is this then show country against this only.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Lh9sYyTRjWziN1ZEg29t?p=preview&preview

Comment: I think you can have a look at the lodash documentation https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#find

Comment: This is not java problem. It should be in JS tag

Answer (score 0):

Your `myJSON` is an array. You have to iterate over it then find if `language === "Dutch"`.

```js
let myJSON = [{
    "language": "Arabic",
    "symbol": "ar",
    "text": "تعمل  على تحسين تصميم وأداء الهياكل والمواد والأنظمة للمشاريع من كل حجم ومستوى التعقيد."
},
{
    "language": "Dutch",
    "symbol": "nl",
    "text": "optimaliseert het ontwerp en de prestaties van constructies, materialen en systemen voor projecten van elke omvang en elk niveau van complexiteit."
}
];
for (index in myJSON) {
if (myJSON[index].language === "Dutch") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON[index].text;
}
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: WOW. Thanks, If I put JSON Code in seperate file, then how fetch the results, Its not working. Kindly explain Jquery script use.